# Why does ggplot2 give me an empty grid when I try to create a line chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like the following:

[Stock Market Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VCPH.png)

All the columns are character types. I want to plot adjusted closing price across time. So, I convert the Date column to a Date class and the Adj.Close column to a numeric type.

```
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date)
data$Adj.Close <- as.numeric(data$Adj.Close)
```

Next, I try to plot the variables

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = "Date", y = "Adj.Close")) + geom_line()
```

But, all I get is an empty grid. I've also tried converting the Date column to a time series data type with `as.ts` but this gives me the same result.

Comment: Use either `aes(x=Date, y=Adj.Close)` or `aes_string(x="Date", y="Adj.Close")`.

Comment: Thanks. This worked.